# How can we import video or audio or images in Hadoop and can do further analysis.

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I know how to import and analyse structured and semi-structured data in hadoop using Pig,hive,sqoop using Json loader and Json serde but how to import  unstructured data like  video or audio or images and how to do further analysis on it.Kindly explain in simple step by step way, if you have any use case of analysing unstructured data that will be of great help.Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Hadoop does not play well with small files, one approach could be to group the binary files into a small number of large files (to avoid dealing 
with big amount of tiny files).

In order to do so, you could convert your binary files (images, audio, video, etc) in sequence files using custom UDFs that aggregates and store them into HDFS.

The following book, Pig Design Patterns, provides some design patterns regarding this topic (see chapter 2).

https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781783285556

Some code snipets  are available on github.

https://github.com/pradeep-pasupuleti/pig-design-patterns/blob/master/Chapter2

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you very much Joseph.It was really a great help.